# Comparing Dates in Database to DateTime.Now

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I have database table in which the dates are stored in the following format

[image]

I need to compare the current system date with the date stored in the db.
I get the system date using `DateTime.Now`

But since these 2 dates are in different formatting... how can i convert and compare so that i can select only the required values.

Comment: after puul out datetime from database they will be in same format so you can compare

Comment: How are you querying the dates from the db and pulling the data into your app? I'd expect that 99% of solutions would give you a native .net datetime object but it's worth asking :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Get **only date** from system datetime and compare with database date column value

You also get only date from database

```
//Database
SELECT CONVERT(date, Transaction_Date) FROM TableName

//Application
if(DateTime.Now.Date==databasedate)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your database column is datetime format then after pull out data and store in a datetime type variable both will be a C# DateTime instance, So you  can compare them without any format specification

```
DateTime date1 = DateTimeFromDb;
DateTime date2 = DateTime.Now;
int result = DateTime.Compare(date1, date2);

if(result == 0 )
  Console.WriteLine("Same")
```